# Facebook Like box disappearing after 45 seconds

Tags: facebook, html

On my website the Facebook Like box disappears after exactly 45 seconds. I even put just the Like box code in it's own html document, verbatim from what I got from the developers site, but still the same outcome, so it seems like a Facebook issue, but I am not sure. I have tried on IE 11, FF 23.0.1, and the latest Chrome but it's the same thing.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[1];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Awesome.Animals" data-width="300" 
    data-height="375" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-
    header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

Comment: I used the iframe option instead of HTML5 and that worked great!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of NoScript. It will be fine if you allow all of Facebook's domains get through (both facebook.com and facebook.net).

Answer (score -1):

For some reason the Facebook JavaScript meddles with the size of the Facebook generated iframe after 45 seconds. Check your browser developer console. Do you see a warning message? 
`fb:share_button failed to resize in 45s`

As a fix, use CSS to force the iframe to be a certain height and width like so:

```
.fb-like-box iframe {
    width: 110px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: This does nothing, and even if it did, FB's JavaScript would still override it.